# Advantages of "normal" over virtual SWT table

Tags: java, swt

I'm in the process of rewriting our table-related SWT/JFace-base GUI framework (making independent of JFace). Currently, some potentially large tables are virtual and all others "normal" non-virtual ones. To simplify my implementation for all tables, I think about making all tables virtual. The only disadvantage I can think of using virtual tables instead of normal ones is, that `tableColumn.pack()` would make the column wide enough for all table rows where as for virtual tables this would only work for those rows where `TableItem`s already are created (== those which were shows or programatically touched).

Are there other disadvantages of using virtual tables?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm using now virtual tables for our projects and I don't see any further disadvantages.